Razor pages - This localhost page can’t be found
After adding a new razor page, all other website pages worked normally but when redirecting to the new page I get HTTP ERROR 404 "This localhost page can’t be found"

MS Visual Studio 2022, Razor pages project.


It's great that you solved your own problem, but for a question to be posted (even if it's self answered), it needs to be answerable by anyone. There's a lack of information here that prevents anyone but yourself from doing so.

@gunr2171 You are absolutely right ! but I tried to mention all the information I have especially the error code and message, if you have any suggestion i'll add them to the question. thanks.

I solved it by editing the project file and removing every ItemGroup that contains the name of the page.

From drop-down menu Project > Edit Project File.
Remove the auto created code blocks (Item Groups) that contains the name of the page name. (in my case "ImageProcessing.cshtml" were mentioned 4 times)
Do not edit or remove any other code

The blocks i removed :

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\ImageProcessing.cshtml" />   </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Remove="Pages\ImageProcessing.cshtml" />   </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Pages\ImageProcessing.cshtml" />   </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\ImageProcessing.cshtml" />   </ItemGroup>


